# Putting object with css properties onto function as argument and set it to DOM element

Tags: javascript

Need your help guys, maybe similar question was asked here, but I didn't find solution.

```
 var someProps = {
        color: 'red',
        background: '#FFFFE0',
        };

function setProp(obj) {
   for (let i = 0, n = someElem.length; i < n; i++)           
      for (var key in obj) {
          someElem[i].style.key = obj[key]
      }
   }
}

someElem.setProp(someProps);
```

someProps - is the object with CSS properties,
someElem - is the array (DOM elements).

As result I want to set CSS properties as in object to all elements in array, as if I've done like this:

```
elem.style.color = 'red';
elem.style.background = '#FFFFE0';
```

Comment: Should be `someElem[i].style[key]= obj[key]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change the `Element` object prototype, you'll need a function with two parameters for that :

```
setProp(elements, cssProperties)
```

- Inside, go through your elements with a `for ... of` loop.
- Then go through your CSS properties with a `for ... in` loop.
- Finally, to edit a property from the `style` object, use the `bracket` notation `style[prop]`

```js
let someProps = {
  color: 'red',
  background: '#FFFFE0',
};

const setProp = (elems,props) => {
  for(let elem of elems){
    for(let prop in props) elem.style[prop] = props[prop];
  }
}

setProp(document.getElementsByTagName('span'), someProps);
```

```html
<span>Test</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Acessing object properties:**

You can change the properties of an object using `object[attribute]` instead of `object.attribute`. Accessing attributes one way or another is equivalent in javascript.

**What you are searching for:**

For your problem, you can define a function that will update your element :

```
function setProp(element, propertyName, value) {        
    element.style[propertyName] = value;
}
```

**Demo**:

```js
const debugElement = document.getElementById('debug');

const properties = {
  color: 'green',
  borderColor: 'white'
};

const ulElements = [1,2,3].map( nId => document.getElementById('l'+nId));

function setProp(element, propertyName, value) {        
    element.style[propertyName] = value;
}

function demo(){
  debugElement.innerHTML = 'Changed !'
  ulElements.forEach(element =>{
    Object.keys(properties).forEach( key=>{
      setProp(element, key, properties[key]);
    })
  })
  
}
setTimeout(demo, 1000)
```

```css
ul{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li{
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
div{
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<ul> 
  <li id='l1'>
  <li id='l2'>
  <li id='l3'>
<ul>

<div id='debug'>Demo : this will change in 1 second</div>
```